# Regex not working in Linux but works on regex101

Tags: regex

When i test the below code on Linux ideally the regex check should fail and exit 1 should be executed but somehow it goes through.

```
build_params="plans-psgdevops_4011.json"
if  ! [[  $build_params =~ ^plans-(sstf-|deploy-|release-|uitest-|other-){1,5}?([a-z0-9~_]+).json ]];
   then
    echo "Filename: $build_params does not follow the correct naming convention."
    exit 1
 fi
 echo "Match went thru " $build_params
```

The same thing tested on regex101.com matches expectations.[image bleow]
[image]

How can we make it work on Linux ??

Comment: Bash does not support nongreedy matching `{1,5}?` or other Perl extensions.